# Spring GetMapping differentiated by @RequestParam only

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have object User defined as:

```
@Entity
public class User {
  private String name;
}
```

In my controller, I want to have mapping to query User by name and also query all users. I would like to do something like this:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public User getUsers() {...}
@GetMapping("/users")
public User getUserByName(@RequestParam String name) {...}
```

Producing:

- api/users
- api/users?name=*myName*

Error is:
{GET /api/users}: There is already 'userController' bean method ... mapped

**Is there possibility in spring to have GET URL mappings differentiated only by query parameters(@RequestParam) ?**

Edit_1: I would like to avoid having to make endpoints for every different getBy variation. So I would like to have only one getBy URI for all different getBy(for name, username, email, address...)

Comment: you can check the param inside a single GET method, if its there do A, if its not then do B.

Comment: Yes, but if user will have 10 values. Email, name, password... and all should be query-able. I will have 10ifs. That is what I would like to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

@GetMapping("/users") public User getUserByName(User user) {...}

Comment: In the method you can determine if the parameters are passed or not

Comment: Is this best practice ? As I mentioned in my edit, if I would like to request object by multiple variables. That means I would need to have RequestParam for every new request. I would like to avoid that.

Comment: you can use object rather than params. for example

@GetMapping("/users")
public User getUserByName(User user) {...}

Spring will cleanly bind your request parameters to your class instance:

Comment: so your multiple variables will mapping to java object.

Comment: It would help if you would put the supporting information to your codesnipet inside your Answer and not the comments. You are always able to edit answers you wrote yourself.